# Total request size (537871149 bytes) must be less than or equal to 50331648 bytes

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, export, geemap

I try to export images from an image collection in .tif by using [this](https://github.com%2Fgiswqs%2Fgeemap%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fexamples%2Fnotebooks%2F11_export_image.ipynb&v=_6JOA-iiEGU) code.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dfIoK5stZcFrtfGDsFLhxIV_VrJNZlxM?usp=sharing

When doing this I got the following error:

> Total request size (537871149 bytes) must be less than or equal to
> 50331648 bytes.

I though it was due to an too large/complex exporting geometry but I tried to export with different geometry and still got the same error. Can someone help me?

Comment: You should post the minimal code to reproduce the error in the question, not a youtube url

Comment: I edit my question with the code I used on colab

Answer (score 2):

That notebook is using the `geemap.ee_export_image_collection` function which uses [geemap.ee_export_image](https://github.com/gee-community/geemap/blob/master/geemap/common.py#L130) which itself calls [ee.Image.getDownloadURL](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-getdownloadurl) under the hood. According to the documentation for this function, the maximum request size is 32 MB:

> Get a download URL for small chunks of image data in GeoTIFF or NumPy format. Maximum request size is 32 MB, maximum grid dimension is 10000.

A better option is to create an Export task:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting_images

In geemap, you also have some functions that wrap this for you, e.g. [geemap.ee_export_image_to_drive](https://github.com/gee-community/geemap/blob/master/geemap/common.py#L326).